# In maven child pom dependencies are not taking version from parent pom dependencies if they are mentioned in a profile

Tags: maven-2, maven

I have a multi-module project, and I am using profiles in the parent pom , which have specific dependencies mentioned in them.
The issue here is that, if in a child pom , I am overriding the dependency element, and mentioning one of the dependencies in the parent pom (which is declared in a profile in parent pom) , the version of that specific dependency needs to be mentioned again.

E.g 
Parent pom

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mycode.apps</groupId>
      <artifactId>jobs</artifactId>
      <version>4</version>   
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
<profiles>
<profile>
    <id>common-dependencies</id>
<activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
</activation>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>com.mycode.apps</groupId>
          <artifactId>dao</artifactId>
          <version>4</version>   
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</profile>
</profiles>
```

Now in child pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
       <!--this one doesnt need a version specified -->
       <dependency>
          <groupId>com.mycode.apps</groupId>
          <artifactId>jobs</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <!--this one makes maven throw an error(if version is not specified) while compilation -->
       <dependency>
          <groupId>com.mycode.apps</groupId>
          <artifactId>dao</artifactId>
       </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Any idea what might be wrong and how can I fix this??

NOTE: The profile is marked as activeByDefault

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this kind of requirments you the [dependencyManagement](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) which is exactly for such cases. Or take look into  the [Sonatype Book](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html#pom-relationships-sect-dep-manage).
This case shouldn't be handled by profiles.